# Can't get (fairly simple) WPF animation working

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I'm trying to get a message panel animated in WPF but has so far achieved no success.

This is the situation:

1. I have a user control with a `StackPanel` containing an `ItemsControl` bound to an (observable) collection in the control's View Model object (`ViewModel.Messages`).
2. When I need to present the user with messages I ad those (as `MessageVM` instances) to the observable collection.

The `ItemsControl`'s visibility is bound to an integer property called `ViewModel.CountVisibleMessages` and there's a converter taking care of translating 0 to `Visibility.Hidden` and positive values to `Visibility.Visible`.

This works just fine. When a message gets added to the collection the `StackPanel` automatically becomes visible and as the user (or a timer) removes the last message it gets hidden. The `StackPanel` height is automatically adjusted to fit all messages of course.

To make everything look nicer I would prefer it if the `StackPanel` resized itself using an animation running for, say, 300 ms. (Ultimately I would also like it to accelerate and deccelerate but that's beyond my ambition right now.

I have experimented for a few hours now but I feel I'm not even close.
Below is my current (not even close to working) XAML at the moment:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Visibility="{Binding CountVisibleMessages, Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibility}}"
                Height="Auto"
                Background="{DynamicResource HmiBackColorLightBrush}">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CountVisibleMessagesChanged}" Value="True" ><!-- I suppose I shopuld've used a Routed Event here but I just needed to get it triggered -->
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin.Bottom"
                                        From="100" <!-- Just a made up value to test the concept -->
                                        To="0"
                                        Duration="0:0:0:3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Style="{DynamicResource Message}">
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="3" Style="{Binding MessageType, Converter={StaticResource MessageTypeToStyle}, ConverterParameter={x:Type TextBlock}}" /> <!-- using dynamic styling here -->
                            <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource HmiCloseMessageButton}" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, ConverterParameter=true}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

(I do realize the above XAML won't get the StackPanel to auto-resize slowly. It's just an experiment to get *anything* happening).

This can't be too difficult I suppose (it's a pretty standard UI behavior in many programs) so I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right directions.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to adjust the bottom margin?  The stack panel VerticalAlignment is top.  If you want to change the Height then bind your StoryBoard Property to Height.   Do you know if your StoryBoard is firing?

Comment: I've tried the Height property with the same (lack of) success. What I really want to achieve is the StackPanel resize itself to fit its content but slowly. I have no idea if the storyboard is firing but I doubt it. Is there anything I can do to test that?

Comment: Have you considered an Expander?  It might be pretty close to what you are trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

The key point is `ExitActions` are necessary for `EnterAction` based dataTrigger animations. So the following seems to be working in my case ....

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="100" x:Name="MyGrid">
   <StackPanel.Style>
      <Style>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
               Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckBox,
                                 Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
               <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                     <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                           Storyboard.Target="{Binding
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                               AncestorType={x:Type 
                                 StackPanel}},
                             BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                           From="100" 
                           To="200"
                           Duration="0:0:1"/>
                     </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
               </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
               <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                     <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                           Storyboard.Target="{Binding
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                 AncestorType={x:Type 
                                   StackPanel}},
                              BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                              To="100"
                              Duration="0:0:1"/>
                     </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
               </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </StackPanel.Style>
 </StackPanel>
 <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid not. There is no visible animation.

Comment: Did u try the way I suggested? Coz the example is working in my case.

Comment: No, I couldn't get it working at all using XAML. Then I tried the code approach and got it running in the end. I then realized manipulating Height was a poor idea as it doesn't look good. 

What I _really_ want is for the fit-to-content  StackPanel to animate up/down from the top of another control as it grows or shrinks. I got that too working using storyboards in code behind. It's "fair enough" but it bugs me I can't get XAML to do the same. Maybe I should post the working code? Perhaps there's a way to get XAML to do the same thing that I'm just too incompetent to know about?